# How to execute an ETL job where multiple py files are compressed to a zip?

Tags: python, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

How would you go about running an ETL job in AWS Glue where the .py files are compressed to a zip, py_files.zip?

```
config.json
init.py
transformations.py
udfs.py
output.py
main.py
```

**main.py**

```
from init import *
from transformations import *
from udfs import *
from output import *
```

What would be the job settings for this and how could set it up in the ETL script to actually run the job?
I've tried  including the file location (S3 bucket) as a *Python/Jar/Other lib path* and tried to import it in the Glue script by importing it:

**Glue script:**

```
from py_files import *
```

I'm quite new to the whole ETL process, what are some best practices for structuring the files to avoid just a single long script where all code is included?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

It mentions zipped python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for an answer, .zip are not supported. You should build a .whl package with all the python modules you want to use, then reference the s3 path of the .whl package in the -extra-py-files in DefaultArguments if you're using Cloudformation or the library parameter if you're using the console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that has the same effect:
1- Upload the files separately into a S3 bucket.
2- Upload them in a zipped file into a S3 bucket.

After that, do the following:
1- Copy the py files/zip file S3 URIs.
2- Go to the Glue Job details.
3- Scroll down and unfold the Additional Properties -> Libraries -> Python library path.
4- Paste the URIs into it. (if you paste multiple URIs make sure to separate them by commas with no spaces in between)

Now the files are setup up.
Inside your job script you should be able to import the modules the same way you've shown in the question.

I hope that helped you.